# Leviticus 5 "..it is hidden from him, and then he comes to know it.." exegesis

Tags: law, leviticus, sin, sacrifice, atonement

> Leviticus 5 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 2 Or if a person touches any unclean thing, whether a carcass of an
>   unclean beast or the carcass of unclean cattle or a carcass of unclean
>   swarming things, **though it is hidden from him** and he is unclean,
>   then he will be guilty.
>
> 3 Or if he touches human uncleanness, of whatever sort his uncleanness
>   may be with which he becomes unclean, and **it is hidden from him, and
>   then he comes to know it**, he will be guilty. 4 Or if a person swears
>   thoughtlessly with his lips to do evil or to do good, in whatever
>   matter a man may speak thoughtlessly with an oath, **and it is hidden
>   from him, and then he comes to know it**, he will be guilty in one of
>   these.

a) Whenever the aforementioned verses say "it is hidden from him" then does it mean "the person in question does Not know whether he/she sinned?"

If yes then when verses Leviticus 5:3 and 5:4 state the following:

"....it is hidden from him, and then he comes to know it..."

b) Does it mean "the person in question does Not know whether he/she sinned, but at some point in time he/she comes to terms with the fact that he/she sinned." ?

c) Furthermore, why does Leviticus 5:2 leave out anything that has the same affect as the following verse that is in Leviticus 5:3 and 5:4?

"..., and then he comes to know it..."

Comment: Since the sin comes from comparison, comparison can only happen with realization, without realization there is no comparison therefore no sin. Only after realization can comparison occur, and after eating the fruit of the discernment without faith then denial falling in the pit of the stages of grief of the spirit, but with acceptance that comes through faith, they leap over the pit and remain steadfast in spirit. And this is how faith overcomes the comparison.

Comment: Look at NIV version than you will find 5:2 has the same structure of 5:3 & 5:4